# custom view for gif image not scaling to size i want

Tags: android

i have problem to scale my custom view PlayGifView i got on internet to display gif images. I tried to inherits from imageView (normally it's View) in order to scale it but it's impossible. It doesn't take in acount the margin too. the weird thing is that i have two types of item in my adapter to display : type in and type out for messages. For the type in, the size is different but this should display the same thing than the type out. The type out take all the width of the screen. None of the two types can be scaled. I need help i've been searching for a long time to fix this. Thanks.
Here's my code :

```
 public class MessagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   public ArrayList<Message> listeMessages;
    Context wContext = null;

    public MessagesAdapter(ArrayList<Message> liste, Context context) {
        this.listeMessages = liste;
        this.wContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listeMessages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listeMessages.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        Message message = (Message) getItem(position);

          int layoutRes=R.layout.listemessagese;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = lInflater.inflate(layoutRes, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.mBody = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            viewHolder.mBodyS = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.texts1);
            viewHolder.mDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            viewHolder.bloc = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bloc);
            viewHolder.iconM = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.men_icon);
            viewHolder.iconM2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.men_icon2);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


        Drawable drawable;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if(message.getType()==TYPE_SORTANT)
        {
            params2.gravity=Gravity.RIGHT;params.gravity=Gravity.RIGHT;
            params2.setMarginStart(70);params.setMarginStart(70);

        }else{
            params2.setMarginEnd(70);params.setMarginEnd(70);
        }
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsR = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        if (message.getTypeEnvoi() == TYPE_SMS) {
            if(message.getType()==TYPE_ENTRANT) {
                viewHolder.mBody.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.mBodyS.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.iconM.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.iconM2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.mBody.setText(message.getBody());

            }else {
                viewHolder.mBody.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.mBodyS.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.iconM.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.iconM2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.mBodyS.setText(message.getBody());
            }

            viewHolder.mDate.setText(convertDate(message.getDate(), "dd MMMM HH:mm  "));
            viewHolder.bloc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {

            viewHolder.mBody.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.mBodyS.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.mDate.setText(convertDate(message.getDate(), "dd MMMM HH:mm  "));

            if(message.getType()==TYPE_ENTRANT) {
                viewHolder.iconM.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.iconM2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                viewHolder.iconM.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.iconM2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.mDate.setLayoutParams(params);
            }

            viewHolder.bloc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.bloc.removeAllViews();
            for (int i = 0; i < message.getBitmaps().size(); i++) {

                Bitmap bitmap = getMmsImage(message.getBitmaps().get(i), wContext);
                ImageView imageB = new ImageView(wContext);
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    //    imageB.setMaxHeight((bitmap.getHeight() / bitmap.getWidth()) * 100);
                     //  imageB.setMaxWidth(100);
                    imageB.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    imageB.setLayoutParams(params);

                    viewHolder.bloc.addView(imageB);
                }
            }
                for (int i = 0; i < message.getImageGifs().size(); i++) {
                    PlayGifView gifView = getGifImage(message.getImageGifs().get(i), wContext);
                    gifView.setLayoutParams(params2);
                    gifView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    gifView.setMaxHeight(50);
                    gifView.setMaxWidth(50);
                    gifView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    viewHolder.bloc.addView(gifView);

                }

                for (int i = 0; i < message.getTabText().size(); i++) {
                    String textMms = message.getTabText().get(i);
                    TextView text = new TextView(wContext);
                    text.setText(textMms);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        if(message.getTypeEnvoi()==TYPE_ENTRANT)
                            drawable = wContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.bubble_yellow3);
                        else
                            drawable = wContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.bubble_blue);
                    } else {
                        if(message.getTypeEnvoi()==TYPE_ENTRANT)
                        drawable = wContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bubble_yellow3);
                        else
                        drawable = wContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bubble_blue);
                    }
                    text.setBackground(drawable);
                    text.setLayoutParams(params);
                    viewHolder.bloc.addView(text);
                }

            }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/typeE">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/men_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/menb_icon"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="70dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:paddingEnd="20dip"
        android:paddingRight="20dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_yellow3"
        />

        <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/texts1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_blue"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginStart="70dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dip"
        android:paddingStart="20dip"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip"
        />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bloc"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/men_icon2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/mendb_icon"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_eff"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

edit : forgot the PlayGifView :

```
public class PlayGifView extends ImageView {

private static final int DEFAULT_MOVIEW_DURATION = 1000;

private Movie mMovie;

private long mMovieStart = 0;
private int mCurrentAnimationTime = 0;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public PlayGifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    /**
     * Starting from HONEYCOMB have to turn off HardWare acceleration to draw
     * Movie on Canvas.
     */
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
}

public void setImageResource(InputStream is){
    mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
    requestLayout();
}



@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if(mMovie != null){
        setMeasuredDimension(mMovie.width(), mMovie.height());
    }else{
        setMeasuredDimension(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), getSuggestedMinimumHeight());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (mMovie != null){
        updateAnimtionTime();
        drawGif(canvas);
        invalidate();
    }else{
        drawGif(canvas);
    }//this changes according to screen size
}

private void updateAnimtionTime() {
    long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    if (mMovieStart == 0) {
        mMovieStart = now;
    }
    int dur = mMovie.duration();
    if (dur == 0) {
        dur = DEFAULT_MOVIEW_DURATION;
    }
    mCurrentAnimationTime = (int) ((now - mMovieStart) % dur);
}

private void drawGif(Canvas canvas) {
    mMovie.setTime(mCurrentAnimationTime);
    mMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

}

Comment: I  used an other class from library  :

compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.16'

I could scaled the size i wanted very simple.